# Translate SQLite database stored data language

Tags: android, sqlite, locale, multiple-languages

I would like to translate my SQLite database data into multiple languages. For example: in the MainActivity[locale-en] I've stored the data into db but I wanna retrieve back the data in Thai after I changed the language to locale-th.

Is there any possible to translate the db data (eg: English, locale-en) to different languages while particular language (eg: Thai, locale-th) is chose? and in Thai can get all data with TH, in English then translate to EN.

Answer (score 0):

You should not translate data at db level. The proper way to implement this is, keep your db data same( as it is now), while displaying data, use translator to translate your existing data in various language.

Android Provides Translator API.

```
String OutputString = Translate.execute("hello",
         Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
```

Make sure INTERNET available.

Comment: Sadly, we couldn't rely on google translate for precise translation. Google translation result couldn't be use for a niche text, like text related with engineering or culture.